# Mock method using mockito, NOT PowerMockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I can not understand how to mock a method like bellow, using on mockito(NOT PowerMockito)

```
public boolean sendSignal(final Class<? extends IAgent> agentClass, final MessageLite signal)
```

I can NOT do it as follows -

```
Mockito.when(plumProxyService.sendSignal(Mockito.any(Agent.class), Mockito.any(MessageLite.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

Where -

```
public abstract class Agent implements IAgent{
...
..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a expectation for any `Agent` when really you want any `Class`.

Try...

```
Mockito.any(Class.class)
```

...instead of...

```
Mockito.any(Agent.class)
```